# Normal distribution, chi-square distribution and t distribution combiened

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

How to prove that when X is from Normal Distribution and Y is from Chi-square Distribution with parameter f and X,Y are independent then X/sqrt(Y/f) is from t distribution with parameter t?

I got this far that I have to solve a quite hard integral and then gave up. Has anyone solved it?

Comment: Are we to assume that your normal distribution has mean $0$ and variance $1$?

Comment: Many difficult integrals can be sorted out if you can recognise the kernel (ignore constant coefficient) as the kernel of the PDF of probability distribution. This is probably the step you got stuck on.

Comment: Yes, normal distribution has mean 0 and variance 1

Comment: I haven't learned Jacobian yet, I have to solve it just true PDFs :/

Comment: What methods have you been taught that let you find the PDF of a variable that is a function of two other variables?

Comment: One theoreme is that when we take V=sqrt(Y/f) and Z=X/V then PDF fZ(x)=∫∞0 v*fx(vx)*fv(v)dv. And then we have to solve that integral .

Comment: In general, if $X$ and $V$ are independent and $Z=X/V$, then $f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(zv)f_V(v)|v|dv$ and in your special case, $v>0$ so this reduces to $f_Z(z)=\int_0^{\infty}vf_X(zv)f_V(v)dv$. Are you sure you copied the theorem down properly as some letters seem swapped? This result can be shown using Jacobian or - effectively what I used in my answer - or change of variable methods. You should end up with the same integral as me, and the same solution method (kernel of gamma pdf) should finish it off.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this can't be shown by considering [moment generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) - often one of the easiest ways to demonstrate relationships between distributions -  as the $t$ distribution has no MGF.

But so long as you can spot the kernel of the integral using standard PDFs (a very handy trick!) it is fairly easy to show that that $T=\frac{X}{\sqrt(Y/f)}$ has the required PDF:

$f_{T}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{f\pi}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(\frac{f+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{f}{2})}\cdot(1+\frac{t^{2}}{f})^{-\frac{f+1}{2}}$
on support $(-\infty,\infty)$

Proof: $Y\sim\chi_{f}^{2}$ has $f_{Y}(y)=\frac{y^{\frac{f}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}}{2^{\frac{f}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{f}{2})}$
on support $[0,\infty)$ and $X\sim N(0,\,1)$ has $f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$
on support $(-\infty,\infty)$. By independence, their joint PDF is
$f_{Y,X}(y,x)=\frac{y^{\frac{f}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}}{2^{\frac{f}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{f}{2})}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^{2}}{2}}$for
$y\geq0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Define the transformed random variables
$W=\frac{Y}{2}$ (so $W\geq0$) and $T=\frac{X}{\sqrt{Y/f}}$
(so $T$ can take all real values and we aim to show $T\sim t_{f}$). Then writing $Y$ and $X$ in
terms of $W$ and $T$ gives $Y=2W$ and $X=T\sqrt{\frac{2W}{f}}$
so $\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}=2$, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=0$
and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=\sqrt{\frac{2w}{f}}$. The Jacobian
is $J(w,t)=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial y}{\partial w} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial w} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}
\end{vmatrix}=2\sqrt{\frac{2w}{f}}$. The joint PDF of $W$ and $T$, on its support $w\geq0$, is:

$\begin{align*}
f_{W,T}(w,t) & =f_{Y,X}(y(w,t),x(w,t))\mid J(w,t)\mid\\
 & =\frac{(2w)^{\frac{f}{2}-1}e^{-w}}{2^{\frac{f}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{f}{2})}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^{2}(2w)}{2f}}\cdot2\sqrt{\frac{2w}{f}}\\
 & =\frac{\sqrt{2w}\cdot w^{\frac{f}{2}-1}}{\Gamma(\frac{f}{2})\sqrt{2f\pi}}\cdot\frac{2^{\frac{f}{2}-1}\cdot2}{2^{\frac{f}{2}}}\cdot e^{-w-\frac{t^{2}w}{f}}\\
 & =\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{f}{2})\sqrt{f\pi}}\cdot w^{\frac{f}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-(1+\frac{t^{2}}{f})w}
\end{align*}$

The marginal PDF of $T$ is then obtained by $f_{T}(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f_{W,T}(w,t)\,\mathrm{d}w$.
The kernel of the integrand is $w^{\frac{f}{2}-1}e^{-(1+\frac{t^{2}}{f})w}$,
recognisably the kernel of a Gamma PDF. Using
$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{n-1}e^{-\lambda n}\mathrm{d}t=\Gamma(n)\lambda^{-n}$
with $\lambda=1+\frac{t^{2}}{f}$ and $n=\frac{f}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$
gives $f_{T}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{f\pi}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(\frac{f+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{f}{2})}\cdot(1+\frac{t^{2}}{f})^{-\frac{f+1}{2}}$
as required.

Some texts put this the other way round: they use what you wrote as the definition of the $t$ distribution and then use this method to obtain the PDF!